# Adding several styles to Kendo grid button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, razorengine

I want to add icons and change the size of a kendo grid button. The engine is razor and here is the code:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<WEB02.ConfigurationModel.TestGrid>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{

    columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Width(110);
    columns.Bound(o => o.Type).Width(130);
    columns.Command(command => {command.Destroy();

    command.Custom("higher Order").Click("showDetails");
    command.Custom("AnotherCommand").Text("   ").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "background:url(/Images/Configuration/Up.png) left no-repeat" });

     });
})
.Sortable()
.Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(true))
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Name))
    .PageSize(100)
    .Read(read => read.Action("ActivityGrid", "Configuration"))
    .Destroy("TestDelete", "Configuration")
    .Events(events => events.Sync("sync_handler"))       
    )


    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true))
```

)

I am able to add only one styling condition to this button using the HtmlAttributes. But i want to add more as i want to change the size of the button as well. Whenever i add any thing to it, the grid malfunction!!
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

*you can add more than one style with html HtmlAttributes.*

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikMvcApp1.Models.PersonViweModel>()
 .Name("PersonList")
 .Columns(col =>
 {
 col.Bound(c => c.FirstName).Width(120);
 col.Bound(c => c.LastName).Width(120);
 col.Bound(c => c.Country).Width(120);
 col.Command(c =>
 {
 c.Edit().HtmlAttributes(new { Style = "background-color:cornflowerblue; color:White" 
 });
 c.Destroy();
 }).Title("Action");
 })

 .ToolBar(t => t.Create())
 .DataSource(source => source
 .Ajax()
 .Model(m => m.Id(e => e.Id))
 .Create("Create", "Home")
 .Update(u => u.Action("Update", "Home"))
 .Destroy("Delete", "Home")
 .PageSize(2)
 .Read(Read => Read.Action("Read", "Home"))
 )
 .Pageable()
 .Groupable()
 .Sortable()
 .Editable()
 .Filterable()
.Width(600)
 )
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several other options instead of going this way:

- Add class instead of adding style, then add CSS for that class
- Use template column
  .ClientTemplate(" Some Text ")